# How to match uppercase and lower case letter in angularjs?

Tags: javascript

I want to match all upper case letter and lower case letter using regular expression, in my code I'm matching only particular character, but I want to match all character irrespective of capital or small. Here is my code

```
$scope.set_color = function(row) {
    var inputString = row.Subject;
    for (i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
        //var findme = "HOT RUSH";
        //var str = findme.match(/\b([a-z][A-Z])\b/);
        var findmeCap = "HOT RUSH";
        var findmeSmall = "hot rush";
        if (inputString.indexOf(findmeCap) > -1 || inputString.indexOf(findmeSmall) > -1) {
            return {
                'background-color': '#FFCCCB'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Can you share a sample `inputString`

Comment: You don't need to have upper and lower case comparison strings and do multiple comparisons. Convert your inputString to lower case and do one comparison.

Comment: so look up regular expressions and learn how to ignore case. But your reg exp is commented out and you are searching for a string, not a reg exp.

Comment: no im coloring table row on the basis on column value. so i need to match charector. if it in upper or lowercase. that row should color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputString = row.Subject;
var findMe = "hot rush";
if(inputString.toLowerCase().indexOf(findMe) !== -1) {
  return {'background-color': '#FFCCCB'};
}
```

This is how I would handle the problem.Regex is not what you need here. And get rid of the for loop.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you code is right, but I'm looping through each row in a table and searching "hot rush" in subject column,if hot rush found then that particular row should be turn to red color, but problem is some row have capital "HOT RUSH" and some rows have small "hot rush" or some row rows have "Hot rush" or "hot Rush" i need to match all these.

Answer (score 2):

You can do string.toUpperCase and string.toLowerCaseAnd then compare the result. And change color accordingly result.

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "HELLO";  
if (a.toUpperCase() === b.toUpperCase()) {
   alert("string is equal");
   //change color 
}
```

Another solution is https://github.com/nickuraltsev/ignore-case

This works like that only so you can use any of these.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked, in my case.

```
$scope.set_color = function (row) {
                       var inputString = row.Subject;
                       for (i = 0; i < inputString.length; i++) {
                           var findMe = "hot rush";
                           if (inputString.toLowerCase().indexOf(findMe) > -1) {
                               return { 'background-color': '#FFCCCB' }
                           }
                       }
                   }
```